# Intellij like Text Editor

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, text-editor

I am Intellij user and get really used to it and especially it's keymap (all kinds of goodies for text: ctrl+w, alt+mouseDrag...). 
What I am looking for now is text editor for programming that would be familiar to Intellij way of work (in some sense).

1. In ideal world, I would like to get similar keymap by default or have it as a plugin.
2. Second best thing would be having keymap to be "very compatible" with Intellij when I set keymap manually. What I mean by that is that, often, its best to stick with tool's keymap, because it is designed in diferent way, for example, I when coming from Eclipse to Intellij, I tried to use eclipses bindings, however I came to conclusion that Intellij is not designed to work that way so I would be missing a lot and some things are not transferable at all.
3. I am willing to pay.

What I have tried/trying:
Notepad++ - Overal good, but annoying (unsaved files, all kinds of popups, even for search), no inline spell-checker.
Sublime Text - Just started trying. Nice that it has good spell-checker, overall seems nice, no annoying popups. What seems to be deal breaker - it has very complex keymap itself, some bindings are not possible (some toggle "on/off: functionality). So it seems that overriding keymap would require a lot of effort and in the and I be missing a lot of sublime features and/or some functionality is not possible.
UltraEdit - not tried, but thinking of trying. Also no inline spell-checker.

Comment: Currently it is not fully possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/43045478/2886891 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5939

Comment: Off-topic for this site. See the sister site, [*Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 16):

I did **Tools -> Create Command-line Launcher** that creates a script in your PATH called **idea**. I always have IDEA open so when I need to modify some file I run

```
idea file-name
```

It is described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-intellij-idea-as-a-diff-or-merge-command-line-tool.html. Notice that the action is not available on Windows, you have to edit the system `PATH` variable instead.